# Streaming record application

Tags: software-recommendation, streaming

Some time ago I was recording streaming radios using an user friendly application. It was able to record without playing, separate files...
Unfortunately, I can’t remember the name of this application in order to use it in 14.04.
Could you help me to find out the name of this application?

Comment: What is the type of the stream? rtmp ?

Comment: I don't know to answer. like this one: http://www.romania-actualitati.ro/

Answer (score 2):

VLC is a good application for streaming audios and videos. You can download and install vlc using the command:

`sudo apt-get install vlc`

And you can follow [this article](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/vlc-streaming.html), it shows you step by step how you can stream a media on VLC.

#### Edit :

I got this, it might help you : [3 best apps for Internet streaming](http://itsfoss.com/apps-internet-streaming-radio-ubuntu/).

Comment: Yes, agree, not being able to find out my old application, VLC is what I use right now. Good, but I still prefer the other one, which I can’t remember about.

Comment: It is preferable that you provide the solution (or a digest) in your answer, and not only a link.

Comment: @LuísdeSousa you mean a software tutorial ?, I don't think that's high time to do.